# Fixed header and footer doesn't stay fixed on my webview app, even though it works fine on the phones regular browser

Tags: javascript, wordpress, android-studio, android-webview

I've made a simple webview app on android studio. The site loads fine and everythings works but not my fixed header and footer.

In order the give the whole app a sense of "App" like feeling, I designed a header and footer that should stay fixed while the center of the site can be scrolled. This works fine on my phones regular browser but doesn't seem to work in the app. I cannot figure out why?

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Hello, @Mattias, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It may be useful, just to be safe, to include the technique you're using to establish a fixed header and footer. I'm assuming you're just using the CSS's `position: fixed`?

Comment: I'm using the Elementor Pro theme so I'm guessing the fixed header is a CSS thing.